# Excel, VBA, web query find string copy cell below paste into cell

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to find the locally used name of a range of room numbers with web query.
The query result is a basic table.
URL needs the variable room number in it.Room numbers are in sheet1 A1:A600
The web query would have a destination to sheet2
find the cell in sheet2 with string "Local Name" copy the cell below it and paste it to the cell next to the current room number in sheet one.
if error or nothing found proceed to next room number.

I have very little vba experience so any help you can provide would be greatly appreciated.

Here is what I think it would resemble:

```
Sub RoomName()    

Dim IE As Object ' InternetExplorer   
Dim roomNum As Range   
Dim localName As String       

Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")   
    IE.Visible = False  

For Each roomNum In Range("A1:A600")

URL = "http://www.nonpublicsite.org/campusname" & roomNum &    

With IE
.Navigate URL

'open the url redirect results to sheet2  
'find string (Local Name) copy cell below the result and paste into sheet1 next to the current room number in the loop  

Sheets("Sheet2").Cells.ClearContents    

On Error Resume Next    
Next roomNum    
End Sub
```

Comment: [Here is an example that was incorrectly posted as an edit to your question](http://pastebin.com/eFuC69NN).